# Typescript/Javascript create array from array with duplicates and create nested array with remaining properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create a new array from an array with a possible duplicate 'show' property. I need only 1 of the duplicate 'show:', but keep all the other properties as a 'performances:' array within the array object.
Example array:

```js
const arr1 = [
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/12/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/3/2020",
        perftime: "9:30 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 5953, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Everyone has dreams that we fear will pass us b… acts are subject to change at any time.</em></p>",
          showName: "I Wish: The Roles That Could Have Been"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/1/2020",
        perftime: "9:30 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6103, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31, 
          showDesc: "<p>In a “Freaky Friday” turn of events, current an… acts are subject to change at any time.</em></p>",
          showName: "Switched: Current & Former Broadway Kids Trade Places"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/13/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/1/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6400, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Broadway mainstay <strong>Christine Andreas</st…Additional food  and beverage minimum of $25.</p>",
          showName: "Christine Andreas"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/22/2020",
        perftime: "9:30 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 4776, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Encore by popular demand! <strong>Join us for F…Additional food  and beverage minimum of $25.</p>",
          showName: "54 Salutes Frank Sinatra"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/18/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/19/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/20/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/21/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      },
      {
        category: "Cabaret",
        perfDate: "2/22/2020",
        perftime: "7:00 PM",
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },
        venueId: 1534
      }
    ]
```

With the resulting array looking like:

```js
const arr2 = [      
      {
        show: {
          showId: 5953, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Everyone has dreams that we fear will pass us b… acts are subject to change at any time.</em></p>",
          showName: "I Wish: The Roles That Could Have Been"
        },
        performances: [
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/3/2020", perftime: "9:30 PM", venueId: 1534}
        ]
      },
      {
        show: {
          showId: 6103, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31, 
          showDesc: "<p>In a “Freaky Friday” turn of events, current an… acts are subject to change at any time.</em></p>",
          showName: "Switched: Current & Former Broadway Kids Trade Places"
        },
        performances: [
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/1/2020", perftime: "9:30 PM", venueId: 1534}
        ]
      },      
      {
        show: {
          showId: 6400, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Broadway mainstay <strong>Christine Andreas</st…Additional food  and beverage minimum of $25.</p>",
          showName: "Christine Andreas"
        },        
        performances: [
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/1/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534}
        ]
      },
      {
        show: {
          showId: 4776, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Encore by popular demand! <strong>Join us for F…Additional food  and beverage minimum of $25.</p>",
          showName: "54 Salutes Frank Sinatra"
        },     
        performances: [
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/22/2020", perftime: "9:30 PM", venueId: 1534}
        ]
      },
      {
        show: {
          showId: 6055, presaleEnd: "", categoryId: 31,
          showDesc: "<p>Leave your expectations at the door as Tony Awa…pearance this summer at Feinstein's/54 Below!</p>",
          showName: "Jeremy Jordan"
        },  
        performances: [
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/12/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534},
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/13/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534},
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/18/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534},
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/19/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534},
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/20/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534},
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/21/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534},
       {category: "Cabaret", perfDate: "2/22/2020", perftime: "7:00 PM", venueId: 1534}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

The nested 'performances can be whatever, I just need to keep all the properties from the duplicated 'show' objects within the array. I am not sure the best way to loop through the original array to accomplish this. I have used .filter() and .find() on an array before, but I have a hard time understanding .reduce() and .map(), but was thinking one of those may be the key. I'm just not sure how to accomplish it.
Thanks!

Comment: Now what is problem? Please show your attempts and what is difficulties? You can not just say: "i need this", you should tell what prevents you from doing this yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce` works great for this sort of thing, but really that's just sugar around a loop. Try to mentally picture how you would *manually* do this, say with a stack of papers. First would be to group the papers into piles where the show is the same (it looks like `showId` is how you can tell this):

```
// Key = showId
// Value = Array of show performances
const performancesByShow = new Map(); 
for (const performance of arr1) { /* TODO: get a better name for this */
  const { showId } = performance.show;
  const performances = performancesByShow.get(showId);
  if (!performances) {
    performances = [];
    performancesByShow.set(showId, performances);
  }
  performances.push(performance);
}
```

Equivalent for `reduce` (doesn't really improve anything):

```
const performancesByShow = arr1.reduce((performancesByShow, performance) => {
  const { showId } = performance.show;
  const performances = performancesByShow.get(showId);
  if (!performances) {
    performances = [];
    performancesByShow.set(showId, performances);
  }
  performances.push(performance);
  return performancesByShow;
}, new Map());
```

Now converting these groupings into your data structure becomes more trivial:

```
const arr2 = performancesByShow.values().map(performances => ({
  show: performances[0].show,
  performances: performances.map(({ category, perfDate, perfTime, venueId }) => ({
    category, perfDate, perfTime, venueId 
  }))
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I got pretty close using a .reduce() while waiting for a response.